# Rails 3 best way to implement the idea of karma?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app that's a simple clone of reddit. Using Devise you can sign up and submit links and vote on them. I started out trying vote_fu_rails_3 but was having a db issue and some other troubles so I went with my own voting solution which just records the link_id, user_id and has timestamps.

I'm trying to implement a way for the votes on your links to count towards a total 'karma' score, ala reddit. Your karma would be your positive votes less your negative votes in total. I'm thinking I need to write a method in the User model (perhaps link model?)

Right now there is no field in the users table for 'karma' or 'link_score' or anything like that. Maybe adding a simple integer column to the Link table and adding or subtracting to it when it's voted on would allow me to do this?

Right now to display the number of votes i'm using link.votes.count which may not be correct (maybe it shows total votes and not total as Up - Down).

[Github Link](http://github.com/caleywoods/rubeddit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to use the features of has_many `:votes, :through => :links` and the sum method.

For additional information check:

- [Ruby on Rails Guide on Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)
- [Ruby on Rails Guide on Calculations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#calculations)

so here's the solution:

**User Table**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

**Links Table**

```
class CreateLinks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :links do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string  :url
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :links
  end
end
```

**Vote Table**

```
class CreateVotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :votes do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :link_id
      t.integer :score
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :votes
  end
end
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links
  has_many :votes, :through => :links

  def karma
    self.votes.sum(:score)
  end

  def positive_votes
    self.votes.sum(:score, :conditions => 'score > 0')
  end

  def negative_votes
    self.votes.sum(:score, :conditions => 'score < 0')
  end

end
```

**Link Model**

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many  :votes
end
```

**Vote Model**

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :link
end
```

The trick is that you set the score to a positive or negative value let's say "+1" for a positive vote and "-1" for a negative vote. **NOTE:** Every vote is a record. The sum will be the total score.

How to use:

```
User.first.karma # gives you total karma
User.first.positive_votes # gives you total positive votes
User.first.negative_votes # gives you total negative votes
```

There are other features you can use like a vote of a "trusted" user could score +5 or -5 etc. etc.

Enjoy!

Comment: this looks great but I must be doing something incorrectly as far as associating my votes to links and the user_id being stored. Let me play around with it some more. Do you idle an IRC channel?

Comment: I'm on freenode in #rails for the next 2 hours, nickname sled_

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be fast, why not add Karma to User model and update it when someone votes up / down? Otherwise, you'll have to continually calculate it every time it is displayed. That could get expensive if you get a lot of users with a lot of karma which I would assume is your goal.

Comment: actually it's a simple query and databases were made for querying and calculating. Your solution may be fine but what if a link is deleted? The votes on that link would still be in the user's karma.

Comment: @sled Couldn't he then also have an `after_destroy` callback that recalculates the karma?